# Kernel Error when starting a notebook in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1704, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 69, in post
    model = yield maybe_future(
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 98, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel_for_session
    kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel
    kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 186, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 337, in start_kernel
    kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 286, in pre_start_kernel
    self.write_connection_file()
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 466, in write_connection_file
    self.connection_file, cfg = write_connection_file(self.connection_file,
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 136, in write_connection_file
    with secure_write(fname) as f:
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 461, in secure_write
    win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
  File "C:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 387, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
    import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I don't know how to fix this. I tried reinstalling anaconda and it did not help. Last time I asked the same question but all I got was: "Run Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install in an Admin command prompt". I don't know what this means. I tried opening cmd and navigating to 'C:\anaconda\Scripts', then I ran "pywin32_postinstall.py -install" in cmd but it just open this file in vscode and nothing was fixed.

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are running it on windows. if you are on windows, you have to install `pywin32`

```
pip install --upgrade pywin32==224
```

After install it, try again, i hope it will work now

Comment: Does not work. Gives me:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32==224

ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32==224

Despite that pywin32 is installed